# Выполнение отдельного потока в неактивном приложении Windows Phone, используя геолокацию

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2013/01/15/how-to-create-application-which-executes-in-the-background-on-windows-phone-8.aspx

На этой странице все подробно изложено. Интересует вопрос, на который автор статьи не ответил: будет ли работать эта схема, если на телефоне отключена геолокация?

Comment: @azaharov, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: В статье автор пишет о том, что можно продолжить выполнение отдельного потока в Windows Phone 8, используя в этом потоке функции геолокации. Т.Е. создателями сделано так, что геолокация может выполняться тогда, когда приложение не активно. Отсюда возникает вопрос, если на телефоне отключена геолокация, то будет ли этот способ работать и не вызовет ли ошибок